# How do I create DNS records

Tags: domains, web-hosting, wordpress, dns

My domain points to a rails app hosted on Heroku. Is it possible to have blog.mydomain.com point to a WordPress installation somewhere else, e.g. Dreamhost?

Answer (score 1):

Add a DNS A record to point the subdomain to the different server's ip address:

```
mydomain.com IN A 321.1.22.55
blog IN A 123.2.33.45.
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your domain provider most have a dns manager. in a normal setup that is untouched there would be 2 A records

1. www @
2. @ 123.2.42.343 <-- this number is different for every host

if you used the Heroku nameservers then you need to make sure you setup the domain to use its built in dns manager and create new a records

Can you post your domain provider and wether or not you are using nameservers or dns manager

So once your you have access to your dns manager then you would create 1 new record and edit 1 record

edit your current @ record and point it to the ip address you have at Heroku then create a new a record with the host being blog and the "points to" to your new host ip address and you can leave the ttl at what ever value

Comment: I didn't quite understand your answer. My blog is at http://otherdomain.com hosted on Dreamhost using Dreamhost's DNS. It has an A record of 173.236.191.68. My Rails app is at http://mydomain.com on Heroku and uses Zerigo DNS manager. I can add records and stuff. My domain registrar is Godady and points to Zerigo's nameservers. What I want to achieve is for blog.mydomain.com to load my blog, like how you use a CNAME record to use a custom domain in Tumblr.

Comment: I tried adding an A record blog.mydomain.com with value of 173.236.191.68 (IP of A record of the blog on otherdomain.com) and it blog.mydomain.com redirects to otherdomain.com.